# ASP: Dynamically update a Google Maps engine instance with new coordinates

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

Forgive me if this doesn't make sense, I'm not 100% sure how to ask it so I'm trying my best and will frequently update this post to reflect any advice people give me on clarifying the question.

I have an ASP page that calls the Google Maps engine API through a script that runs on page load (just declared in the page itself, not in the PageLoad method). Not knowing much about JS or the Maps API I simply followed Google's instructions for embedding it in the page and passing coordinates to it for a marker. What I ultimately need to do is be able to feed updated coordinates into it as the object it's tracking changes position, so the map on the page shows the marker moving in "real-time" (5-second refresh). The coordinates are being updated in a SQL table and I have a data source pulling them on a 5-second timer, so I actually have the data on the page, but I don't know how to get the Maps instance to update when that happens because for now it's just got hard-coded coordinates in it.

So my question is, what is the best way to go about updating the Maps instance with these changing coordinates? Is there a way to re-run that script with new coordinates? Or should this involve an update panel somehow? Am I going about this in the completely wrong way? I don't want to have to refresh the entire page because that will affect performance and user experience.

For reference, my page contains something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Panel1 not refreshed yet"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="mac" DataValueField="mac" Height="28px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<script>
  // Some JS here that calls the map and adds the coordinate to it
</script>
```

The update panel handles a data source and updates a list and a label with information from that data source every 5 seconds. The script is mostly straight from Google's own examples of how to embed the map in a page with a coordinate marker in it. I think i need to add something in the panel to rerun the script when the timer ticks, but being unfamiliar with ASP I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I've tried simple things like just pasting the script inside of it but the page crashes as soon as it hits a reference to any Google API classes (big surprise). I feel like I'm frustratingly close but can't make the last simple connection. I'm used to working with C# applications that can run loops however I want them and push updates to whatever part of a form I need, but integrating this JS in is what's tripping me up. Hopefully that makes sense, it's late and I'm tired (:

**Update:** I've got the map to load by declaring the script with as large a scope as possible in the `<script>` element below the head of the page (that contains all the rest of the C# code) and then referencing the `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` in the `Page_PreRender` method. This loads the map fine on page load, but when the timer ticks it simply blanks out the Div where the map was. I tries using [this trick](http://forums.asp.net/t/1070810.aspx) to get the script to execute every time the panel updates (by putting the button in the panel and referencing it in the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method) but all this seems to do it re-register the script every time there's a tick event. If I watch the debugger I can see the header slowly fill up with new references to the script as it's registered each time. I think I'm pretty darn close to having this figured out but I need help rearranging things a bit. For reference, this is what the PreRender code looks like now, with "script" being the string containing the script itself:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Button1, Button1.GetType(), "MapRefresh", script, true);
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+maps+update+via+ajax

Comment: I think that might put me on the right track but I don't know enough about ajax to know which result holds the key or how to integrate it into my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've managed to solve it but unfortunately I had to bring in a coworker who knows javascript to do it. He modified the script that calls the map and places markers on it to run a loop that checks the datasource and manages the adding/deleting of the markers via a temporary array that holds the position of the active markers while it clears the whole map and then rewrites them to it, leaving out any that don't exist in the datasource any more. He had to use a self-revealing method to do it, calling only specific functions repeatedly instead of the whole script.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should involve an UpdatePanel with AsyncPostbackTrigger

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger(v=vs.100).aspx

But the control that will trigger the AsyncPostBackTrigger will be an timer with 5sec updating  the coordinates, as you said.

Comment: So how do I make that trigger the script defined in the page? I have a timer and update panel already set up but they call C# code and SQL queries to update the data sources, I'm not sure how to include the JS script element that loads the map.

Comment: Something like that:

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
                             runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimerID" EventName="Timer_Tick_Event" />
                </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: I do actually have that panel and trigger in there (see my edit above) but I'm not sure how to make if affect that script which is defined elsewhere

Comment: I don't think i'll help you much, but... try this in code behind in Tick event.
Change the 'MyFunction' to the name of your function that google maps gave you

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);

Comment: Funny thing is I just discovered a reference to something very similar somewhere else and I think it's the answer. I've set up the script inside the Tick method and declared the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock method (which looks the same as the one you suggested) but now I just have to figure out how to output it to the actual page. It was originally in a Div above the update panel and the actual script references that Div (this is the default way Google has you embed it) so I need to get the script to render it in the panel somehow.